# Google Drive Node.Js TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined driveResponse.id

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

I am attempting to retrieve an Id from a copied Google Drive file. Whenever I try to retrieve driveResponse.id it always comes back as undefined. Here is the code that matters:

```
let request = {
        name: title,
      };
    var template = '1234567890987654321';
    var presentationId;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      drive.files.copy({
        fileId: template,
        resource: request,
      }, (err, driveResponse) => {
          if (err){
              console.log("There was an error: " + err);
          }else{
            console.log('Created presentation with title: ' + title);
    //error happens here
            let presentationCopyId = driveResponse.id;
            console.log(presentationCopyId);
            resolve(presentationCopyId);

            r2.question("Presentation Id: ", function(presentationIdIn){
                presentationId = presentationIdIn;
                console.log("Please wait");
                r2.close();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: response driveResponse has property 'id' ?  you need check

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy driveResponse does not have `id` field.

Comment: is driveResponse null?

Comment: @Mars.Tsai It does, it shows up in the json if you put your fileId in the "Try This API" window. , let presentationCopyId = driveResponse.id; console.log(presentationCopyId); logs as undefined in the console.